# How do I add a simple onclick on a JavaScript mustache template?

Tags: javascript, templates, template-engine, mustache

I have a simple mustache template:

```
var template = "<button style='background: red;'>{{label}}</button>";
```

And the data:

```
var data = {

    label: "Click me!"

}
```

Which works great with when doing the classic transformation:

```
var html = Mustache.to_html( template, data );
```

But my question. How do I add a simple `onclick` function on my button, which I define in the indata?

Answer (score 0):

Add an "onclick" atribute with code to execute as an argument.

`<button onclick='alert("I was called!")' style='background: red;'/>`

Comment: I am not really keen on hard-coding that in the template, but rather have it in my data instead. I also want to add more sophisticated functions than an alert :-)

Comment: Then you just do it like this: onclick="{{onclick}}" and var data={
onclick: "blahblah"
}

In onclick you can type any javascript expression or function.

Comment: As I wrote to cur4so, using a function only gives an undefined. I could return a string, but that seems to ruin the whole purpose of using a function? dl.dropbox.com/u/8183146/temp/onclick.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var template = "<button style='background: red;'>{{onclick}}</button>";

var data = {

    onclick: function(){
             // content of your function 
             }

}
```

The answer of JanL is right in essence

Comment: This results in "<button style="background: red;">undefined</button>" - I guess I have to return the value from the function as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think the point of the question is that your page should not need to wire up events until it knows what template it may or may not be using. Load your template from an external html file and add a script with your events underneath your template definition

Answer (score -2):

Using jQuery's built-in .on('click') event handler:

```
$("button").on('click', function() {
  alert("I was clicked!");
});
```